# Programmatically avoid Google OpenID access request

Tags: google-api, openid, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am providing my Google Apps Domain users content via Google Sites.

Furthermore I have 3rd party content which I would like to integrate. This content needs to be secure and available only to the Google Apps Domain users.

I have implemented openid which authenticates that the users are from my domain. I consider the users to be "stupid" so I wish to avoid any access request pages, which also makes my site look rather unprofessional / unpolished.

I can see the security setting under my personal account here:

https://www.google.com/settings/security

Is there anything in the SDK which will allow me upon user creation to add the necessary account permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hypothetically if you can host your 3rd party content on [Google app Engine](https://appengine.google.com/) (GAE) and all  your users reside in your Google Apps Domain it is possible to set Authentication Type to "Google apps Domain" More about GAE authentication can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth)

Do not forget to deploy GAE under same Google apps Domain account

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look in more detail at the suitability of this.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization protocols like OpenID and OAuth have been deliberately designed to require explicit user confirmation of access privileges. Any mechanism that bypassed user intervention would effectively be a security exploit. I'd recommend you save yourself time and frustration by accepting that you're not going to get around that interstitial authorization page.

For better or worse, scope authorization pages have become a well-established part of the modern web application landscape. Users these days routinely confirm authorization dialogs for Facebook, Google+, LinkedIn, and Twitter access without batting an eyelash. Your less savvy users may not recognize it as such, but using existing security mechanisms is a sign of *greater* professionalism than rolling your own.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but as the domain administrator I would of hoped that we could grant access for our users, just the same as we can other google apps features.